# Project embedded document fields after lookup operation

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I want to do a join between Timesheet:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = TIMESHEET_COLLECTION)
public class Timesheet {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private ObjectId employeeId;
    private LocalDate date;
    private String occupationTitle;
    private BigDecimal salary;
    private List<TimesheetEntry> entries;
}
```

and Employee (as embedded document):

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = Employee.EMPLOYEE_COL)
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String registry;
    private String cpf;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String nickname;
    private String phone;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private LocalDate admissionDate;
    private EmployeeOccupation occupation;
    private EmployeePaymentPreferences paymentPreferences;
    private Map<String, String> equipmentPreferences;
    private Boolean active;
}
```

So I have this **aggregation** query, with **match**, **lookup**, **unwind** and **projection** operations.

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchTimesheetFilter(timesheetFilter), lookupEmployee(), unwindEmployee(), projectEmployee());
```

There are lookup and unwind implementations. I'm unwinding because employee should be a single object, not an array.

```
private LookupOperation lookupEmployee(){
    return LookupOperation.newLookup()
            .from("employee")
            .localField("employeeId")
            .foreignField("_id")
            .as("employee");
}

private UnwindOperation unwindEmployee(){
    return Aggregation.unwind("employee");
}
```

It returns successfully a **Timesheet document** with a **embedded Employee document**. The point is: I **don't want all data** from employee. I only want a **few fields**.

So, I tried to exclude unwanted fields from employee, using my projection operation:

```
private ProjectionOperation projectEmployee() {
    return Aggregation.project().andExclude("employee.nickname", "employee.firstName", "employee.fullName");
}
```

It didn't work. My embedded employee is still being returned with all fields. However I can successfully exclude fields from Timesheet, if I do something like this:

```
private ProjectionOperation projectEmployee() {
    return Aggregation.project().andExclude("startDate", "endDate");
}
```

How can I project custom fields from a document embedded through a lookup operation?

Comment: Can you show your schema?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti updated!

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to exclude `"employee.nickname", "employee.firstName", "employee.fullName"`, instead of `"nickname", "firstName", "fullName"`

Try this:

```
private ProjectionOperation projectEmployee() {
    return Aggregation.project().andExclude("employee.nickname", "employee.firstName", "employee.fullName");
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's what I tried, actually. I pasted it wrong here. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

i did it this way (not sure if it's right but it works):

```
private LookupOperation lookupEmployee(){
    return LookupOperation.newLookup()
            .from("employee")
            .localField("employeeId")
            .foreignField("_id")
            .as("employeeLookup");
}
```

`no unwind used`

`Aggregation.project().and("employeeLookup.firstName").`as`("employee.firstName")`